# NULL NOT IN (Empty_Relation) of SQL query shows different behaviors on different engines

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-null

I try a query which test NULL NOT IN Empty_Relation on Postrgresql, Spark and I got different results.

```
select count(*) from
(select 1)
where null not in
(a empty relation)
```

Postgresql outputs 1. 
The other outputs 0.

I understand the NULL behaviour of NOT IN, but my the subquery is empty relation, this situation seems more interesting.
There are a lot of posts discussing NOT IN but I don't find anything related to NOT IN Empty_Relation.

So my question is more like does ANSI SQL define this behavior or this is actually a grey area, both answers could be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**: PostgreSQL is correct.

This is what the SQL specification says about this behavior:

> 4) The expression `RVC NOT IN IPV` is equivalent to `NOT ( RVC IN IPV )`
>
> 5) The expression `RVC IN IPV` is equivalent to `RVC = ANY IPV`

So, `NULL NOT IN (<empty relation>)` is equivalent to `NOT (NULL = ANY (<empty relation>))`

Then, it goes on to say:

> The result of `R <comp op> <quantifier> T` is derived by the application of the implied `<comparison predicate>` `R <comp op> RT` to every row `RT` in `T`.
>
> [...]
>
> d) If `T` is empty or if the implied `<comparison predicate>` is False for every row `RT` in `T`, then `R <comp op> <some> T` is False.

(Note: `<some>` is either `ANY` or `SOME` -- they both mean the same).

By this rule, since `T` is empty, `NULL = ANY (<empty>)` is False, so `NOT (NULL = ANY (<empty relation>)` is True.

Comment: To me it's helpful to say that NULL means "undefined". When I asked whether "some undefined value" is `IN (... empty relation ...)`, there is no doubt it _isn't_ there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure Postgres is correct.

Although almost every comparison with `NULL` returns `NULL`, you have found an exception.  If the set is empty, then *nothing* is in the set.  That is, *any value* is NOT in the set regardless of the value.

Remember, the semantics of `NULL` mean "unknown" value -- *not* missing value.  "Unknown" means that it can take on any value.  The expression `<anything> not in (<empty set>)` is true, regardless of the value of `<anything>`.

Incidentally, Postgres is not alone in this behavior.  A cursory look shows that SQL Server and Oracle also return `1` for equivalent queries.