# NOT IN implementation of Presto v.s Spark SQL

Tags: null, apache-spark-sql, presto, isnull

I got a very simple query which shows significant performance difference when running on Spark SQL and Presto (3 hrs v.s 3 mins) in the same hardware.

```sql
SELECT field 
FROM test1 
WHERE field NOT IN (SELECT field FROM test2)
```

After some research of the query plan, I found out the reason is how Spark SQL deals with `NOT IN` predicate subquery.
To correctly handle the NULL of NOT IN, Spark SQL translate the `NOT IN` predicate as `Left AntiJoin( (test1=test2) OR isNULL(test1=test2))`.

Spark SQL introduces `OR isNULL(test1=test2)` to ensure the correct semantics of `NOT IN`.

However, the `OR` of Left AntiJoin join predicate causes the only feasible physical join strategy for `Left AntiJoin` is `BroadcastNestedLoopJoin`. For current stage, I could rewrite NOT IN to NOT EXISTS to workaround this issue. In the query plan of NOT EXISTS, I could see the the join predicate is `Left AntiJoin(test1=test2)` which causes a better physical join operator for NOT EXISTS (5 mins to finish).

So far I am lucky since my dataset currently does not have any `NULL` attributes, but it may have in the future and the semantics of NOT IN is what I really want.

So I check query plan of Presto, It does not really provides `Left AntiJoin` but it uses `SemiJoin` with a `FilterPredicate = not (expr)`. The query plan of Presto does not provide too much info like Spark.

So my question is more like:

Could I assume Presto has a better physical join operator to handle `NOT IN` operation? Not like Spark SQL, it does not rely on the rewrite of  join predicates `isnull(op1 = op2)` to ensure the correct semantics of NOT IN in the logical plan level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am actually the person who implemented `NULL` treatment for semi join (`IN` predicate) in Presto.

Presto uses "replicate nulls and any row" replication mode in addition to hash-partitioning¹, which allows it to process `IN` correctly in the presence of `NULL`s on either side of the `IN`, without falling back to broadcasting, or making the execution single-threaded or single-node. The runtime performance cost is practically the same as if `NULL` values didn't exist at all.

If you want to learn more about Presto internals, join the `#dev` channel on [Trino Community Slack](https://trino.io/slack.html).

¹) to be precise, semi join is hash-partitioned or broadcast, depending on cost-based decision or configuration.

Comment: Could I interpret you answer in below way?
 
NULL also get participate in the JOIN operation (in other words, NULL would be sent to each partition if the predicate subquery indeed produced the NULL)

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Plus some non-NULL value to correctly distinguish `NULL IN (empty subquery)` queries (which produces `false`, as per SQL spec, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58685400/65458)

Comment: Also curiously about does `SemiJoin` still have knowledge about it comes from `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`?  Since the NULL of the left hand side for `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` apparently needs different logic to handle. Thanks.

Comment: Let's talk more on the slack.