# Does Presto support NOT IN constructs?

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I have a query of the form:

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_id
FROM my_table
WHERE person_id NOT IN (SELECT person_id FROM my_table WHERE status = 'hungry')
```

In `my_table` there are multiple rows for each person, and I want to exclude those people who have ever had status "hungry". This is a construct I regard as standard and have used in other SQL dialects, but this brings me back an empty result set in Athena.

On the other hand, the plain old `IN` construction works as expected.

Can anyone explain how I can write this query in Presto? I found [another article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58735664/not-in-implementation-of-presto-v-s-spark-sql) on SO that seems to imply it works correctly, so I am a bit nonplussed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use `NOT IN`.  If *any* returned values are `NULL` then it returns no rows.  Note:  This is how SQL works, not a peculiarity of any particular database.

Instead, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.person_id
FROM my_table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT  
                  FROM my_table t2
                  WHERE t2.status = 'hungry' AND
                        t2.person_id = t.person_id
                 );
```

Actually, I might suggest aggregation for this instead -- you are already doing aggregation essentially with the `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
select person_id
from my_table t
group by person_id
having sum(case when status = 'hungry' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: Ha, I'd assumed it wouldn't be the case but it does indeed turn out we have NULL IDs in that table! The EXISTS construct works - thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would do aggregation :

```
SELECT person_id
FROM my_table
GROUP BY person_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'hungry' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

If you want full row then use `NOT EXISTS` , NOT IN would return no row if sub-query have null :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.person_id
FROM my_table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1  
                  FROM my_table t1
                  WHERE t1.status = 'hungry' AND
                        t1.person_id = t.person_id
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT person_id
FROM my_table m
GROUP BY person_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN status='hungry' THEN 1 END)=0
```

Comment: Thanks, nice idea, but wouldn't I need SUM rather than COUNT?

Comment: No, that version is correct too. COUNT omits NULL values, so effectively it would count only occurences of "hungry"

Answer (score 0):

I feel compelled to point out that you can solve this by just excluding the NULLs explicitly from the subquery, and sticking with the NOT IN construct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_id
FROM my_table
WHERE person_id NOT IN (SELECT person_id FROM my_table WHERE status = 'hungry' AND person_id IS NOT NULL)
```